# How to properly use setHttpUserAgent in PyQt 5.13

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am working on PyQt5 and my version is 5.13. In the documentation

(https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython-dev/PySide2/QtWebEngineWidgets/QWebEngineProfile.html#PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets.PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineProfile.setHttpUserAgent)

```py
webview = QWebEngineView()
agent = u"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246"
profile = QWebEngineProfile.setHttpUserAgent(agent)
webpage = QWebEnginePage(profile, webview)
webview.setPage(webpage)
webview.show()
```

according to the above documentation link, the user agent string type is Unicode which is created but when i run the code, the error comes

```
profile = QWebEngineProfile.setHttpUserAgent(agent)
TypeError: setHttpUserAgent(self, str): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QWebEngineProfile'
```

how to solve this Type Error ? as per my knowledge their is not a QWebEngineProfile type of string

Comment: There's no need to create a new page/profile. Just do `webview.page().profile().setHttpUserAgent(agent)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineProfile, QWebEnginePage


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.webview = QWebEngineView()
        webpage = QWebEnginePage(self.webview)

        self.useragent = QWebEngineProfile(self.webview)

        agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246"
        self.useragent.defaultProfile().setHttpUserAgent(agent)

        self.webview.setPage(webpage)
        self.webview.setUrl(QUrl("http://whoer.net/"))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.webview)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: it worked ... thanks for giving me code ... can you tell me what's the main issue ? according to my code